# I moved few scripting files from one location to another. I didn't mention names to those files in the destination

Tags: shell

I have two scripting files to be moved to a new directory. 
with mv command I moved those files but couldn't find them in the new directory.

I did a mistake of not providing the filenames in the destination folder. The files are not present anywhere. How to get my files back?

from user1 I moved files 
sudo mv script1 /infinitescripts
sudo mv script2 /infinitescripts

I expected script1 and script2 files to be present in infinitescripts directory. But, the directory is empty and the files are not present in the source as well. I dont know where my files are gone.

Comment: Quick question before I answer - is `infinitescripts` a directory _inside_ of the directory that script1 and script2 were in? For example, if script1 and script2 were in a folder `myscriptfolder`, were you trying to move them to `myscriptfolder/infinitescripts`?

Comment: Please post the result of `stat infinitescripts`

Comment: @thisisbenmanley, your assumption is exactly true.

Comment: @kamilCuk, the result of infinitescripts after issuing the command is its just empty. That is bothering me. My files are not in the source as well as in the dest where I moved

Comment: and `stat /infinitescripts`. - you are aware there are `/` in front in the command you posted? `its just empty` - what does that mean "it's just empty"? Ther eis no such file or directory? the file does not exists? the file is empty? `stat` has to output something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have a file `myfile` in folder `A` (so, `A/myfile`), and I want to move that file into a folder `B` *inside* of folder `A` (so, into `A/B/`), I need to use `mv myfile B`. That will result in there being a file `A/B/myfile`.

What you ran was the equivalent of `mv myfile /B`, with that extra `/` in front. What the extra `/` does is tell the system to look in the *root directory* for that folder.

So what you did was accidentally created a folder in the root directory called infinitescripts and moved your file into there. The file should be safe and sound. To find it, you can go to that directory with

`cd /infinitescripts`.

Comment: Exactly! after a while I realized my mistake. I found my scripting files in the root folder. Thank you so very much.